# Problem with gesture in Xcode 12 and iOS 14

Tags: swift, gesture, ios14, xcode12

I have a problem after upgrading to Xcode 12 and iOS 14.

Scenario:
I have a Nested UITableView: **nestedTableView**. Like below

```
class GAllowGestureEventPassTableView: UITableView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var allowGestureEventPassViews: [UIView] = []
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        guard let otherView = otherGestureRecognizer.view else { return false }
        print("tableView  : \(type(of: otherView))")
        if allowGestureEventPassViews.contains(otherView) {
            print("allowGestureEventPassViews contains  : \(type(of: otherView))")
            print("gesture pass  ")
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Then I add another UITableView to **nestedTableView**'s allowGestureEventPassViews array. so I can control which tableView can be scroll.

```
    self.nestedTableView.allowGestureEventPassViews.append(controller.tableView)
```

In Xcode 11.7, iOS 14 worked just fine.

Log:

```
tableView  : GAllowGestureEventPassTableView
tableView  : GAllowGestureEventPassTableView
tableView  : GAllowGestureEventPassTableView
tableView  : UITableView
allowGestureEventPassViews contains  : UITableView
gesture pass
```

but after upgrading to Xcode 12 gesture seen to be different.
In Xcode 12 The gesture never pass through the **nestedTableView**.

```
tableView  : GAllowGestureEventPassTableView
tableView  : GAllowGestureEventPassTableView
tableView  : GAllowGestureEventPassTableView
tableView  : UITableViewCellContentView
```

Does anyone has the same problem? or an I misunderstand something about iOS14 gesture.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found the answer.

In iOS14 some reason, **UITableViewCellContentView** hierarchy is different.

In **tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)** I add subview

```
 cell.addSubview(contentScollView)
```

**UITableViewCellContentView** is blocking the gesture.

Change to

```
 cell.contentView.addSubview(contentScollView)
```

This solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you for discovering this so quickly! Helped a lot

Comment: Apple is really messing with me with this iOS14 release. Good eye. In my case it was a UICollectionView inside of a UITableViewCell

Comment: Wow I can't believe, this thing messes with all my app. How come they do things like that?!

Comment: Wow THANK YOU! I would have never found that myself :)

Comment: Does anybody know that how to fix in OBJC? it's was working like charm but after iOS 14 it's not working!

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C:

```
[self.contentView addSubview: contentScollView];
```