# What is solution to avoid touch event on cell (this cell contains tableview) of Tableview

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios14

A cell contains another tableview and there is different behaviour of build generated by xCode 12.0 and 11.0.

`didSelect` method of tableview on cell (which contains another tableview) is called with xCode 12.0 build.

But...

`didSelect` method of tableview on cell (which contains another tableview) is not called with xCode 11.0 build (expected behaviour).

What to do with this scenario?

Comment: Your problem might be related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63987896/problem-with-gesture-in-xcode-12-and-ios-14

Comment: @RemcoNijhuis correct ! got the solution now thanks